# Fencing $n$ points while keeping minimum distance $d$ from each point

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Consider this problem

**I have a land consisting of $n$ trees. Since the trees are favorites to cows, I have a big problem saving them. So, I have planned to make a fence around the trees. I want the fence to be convex (curves are allowed) and the minimum distance from any tree to the fence is at least $d$ units. And I definitely want a single big fence that covers all trees.

You are given all the information of the trees, to be specific, the land is shown as a $2D$ plane and the trees are plotted as $2D$ points. You have to find the perimeter of the fence that I need to create as described above. And you have to minimize the perimeter.**

[One tree, a circular fence is needed](http://lightoj.com/data/problems/desc/1239/g1.png)

[Two trees, the fence is shown](http://lightoj.com/data/problems/desc/1239/g2.png)

I was told the solution for $n>3$ was the perimeter of the convex hull 
$+2\pi d$

where $d$ is the minimum distance I must maintain from each point (tree).

But how?

Edit : I couldn't add the pictures. So,the links [Image 1 and 2](http://lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1239)

Comment: The enclosed region will be $C\oplus B$, where $C$ is the convex hull of the trees, $B$ is the disc of radius $d$, and $\oplus$ means "Minkowski addition". The formula $p(C\oplus B)=p(C)+p(B)=p(C)+2\pi d$ will  turn up if you wiki "Minkowski addition". ($p(\cdot)$ means perimeter.)

Comment: Wow thanks , I don't know about the term .I just searched and yeah it's a formula .I wish I had a great geometry background,However I will try to understand.

Comment: Alternatively, draw a rectangle of width $d$ along each edge of the convex hull to connect it to the fence. The extra perimeter is because of the circular arcs at each vertex, and you can fit those arcs together into a circle of radius $d$.